# MS graph - attaching large files. The audience claim value is invalid 'aud'

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I am using msal to get accesstoken which is sent to a php server which uses ms graph calls.
Until now I am able to create a draft emails, attach files and send the emails.
However, I am not able to attach large files. I am following the guide in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/outlook-large-attachments?tabs=http.

I am able to create upload session and get the url successfully but encounter the invalid audience error when using put request to upload url.

The access token has openid, profile, user.read, mail.send and mail.readwrite scopes. for some reason i cannot get token with offline_access scope through msal.

Answer (score 1):

As per the documentation you pointed to for the upload PUT

> Do not specify an Authorization request header. The PUT query uses a pre-authenticated URL from the uploadUrl property, that allows access to the https://outlook.office.com domain.

You need to exclude sending the accessToken which is going to be invalid for that endpoint

Comment: Thanks. I was using msgraph library to upload PUT request. I used clean guzzle lib and it worked.